# Unity DE on GalliumOS: Why might my scroll direction be ignoring dconf settings?

Tags: xfce, scrolling, unity

I'm running GalliumOS 2.0 ([release details](https://www.reddit.com/r/GalliumOS/comments/4qz25n/galliumos_20/)) ([home page](https://galliumos.org/)) because it's nearly perfect for my setup. The only issue is that I really don't like the desktop environment. I much prefer Unity, so I installed ubuntu-desktop. The only issue present is that the scroll direction is 'natural', and I prefer reversed.

The issue is only present while in Unity. I'm able to use the XFCE4 Mouse and Touchpad settings menu to reverse it, which works perfectly in the XFCE4 environment but doesn't carry over to the Unity environment. Using Unity Tweak Tool, the Scrolling section does not have an option for direction. The standard Settings menu does not have any scrolling options in the Mouse section.

As the title suggests, I tried editing the dconf file which controls the scroll direction, but that setting seems to be ignored.

I realize Unity uses Compiz for settings, and (correct me if I'm wrong) XFCE4 uses gnome. I think this is somehow the cause of the issue, but from what I know, when I log in to the Unity environment, shouldn't it load my settings from Compiz? That being said, is dconf not part of Compiz? Alternatively, is there a way to make Unity load settings like the touchpad control from gnome?